# how to dynamically create an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which is created by pulling data from a csv file. The array looks like the following (when printed).

```
Array[4]
0:Object
    value1:"200"
    value2:"95"
    value3:"6395"
    value4:"2"
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
```

The way I created it is the following.

```
var strCSV = e.target.result;
var arrCSV = strCSV.match(/[\w .]+(?=,?)/g);
var noOfCols = 4;

// To ignore the first row which is header
var hdrRow = arrCSV.splice(0, noOfCols);

var data = [];
while (arrCSV.length > 0) {
    var obj = {};
    // extract remaining rows one by one
    var row = arrCSV.splice(0, noOfCols)
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        obj[hdrRow[i]] = row[i].trim();
    }
    // push row to an array
    data.push(obj)
}
```

So let's say now I want to create another array of objects, with the same data values, but different keys.

```
var tableData = [
        {key1: "", key2: "", key3: "", key4: ""}];
```

I've tried different ways to do I haven't been able to do it. For example I tried the following.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    tableData[i]["key1"] = data[i].value1;
}
```

Or something with a similar form. I created an empty array tableData = [] thinking that creating the elements on the spot would do the trick, but it won't. Is there anyway to do this? I can't just create a object and copy all the elements from the first array one by one as the number of elements in the first array could be anything.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you're asking.  What would your output format look like?

Comment: You forgot to init the object. Using this will init object and set value:  tableData[i] = {key1: data[i].value1}

Comment: Is there a variable number of keys in each object? in other words, can the second object have `value1:"1200"` and the third `value4:"3",value5:"22"`? In which case, how are you mapping from one key name to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    var obj = { "key1": data[i].value1, "key2": data[i].value2};
    tableData.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. @Den Isahac, I know you posted the same answer but I have to choose one answer.  Thanks both.

Comment: I upvoted his answer so he can also get credit for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of random objects and values using the following code below.
First, create an array using where *12* is the **length** and then the object.

```js
const data = Array.from({
    length: 12
}, () => ({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1,
    name: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)
}))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new object, then appending it to the tableData array.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    var newData = { "key1" : data[i].value1 };
    tableData.push(newData);
}
```

Comment: We both posted the same solution nearly at the same time. Now that's what I call aligment of thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// declare array
var tableData = []; 

for (...) {
    // create new object
    var obj = { key1: "", key2: "" }; 

    // add obj to array
    tableData.push(obj); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to `tableData[i]["key1"]` until you first put an object into `tableData[i]`.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    tableData[i] = {};
    tableData[i]["key1"] = data[i].value1;
}
```

You can also combine the object initialization and property assignment:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    tableData[i] = {key1: data[i].value1};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you assign the keys directly from your csv headers to your object? That way you only need to parse it once and don't need additional loops and work..

```js
var csv = `foo,bar,baz\na,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i`;

function parseCsv(str) {
  let split = str.split("\n");
  let header = split.shift().split(',');
  let res = [];

  split.forEach((line) => {
    let o = {};
    line.split(',').forEach((el, i) => {
      o[header[i]] = el;
    })
    res.push(o);
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(parseCsv(csv));
```

Or, if you have different headers you want to assign:

```js
let csv = `foo,bar,baz\na,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i`;
let header = ["head1", "head2", "head3"];
function parseCsv(str) {
  let split = str.split("\n");
  split.shift();
  let res = [];

  split.forEach((line) => {
    let o = {};
    line.split(',').forEach((el, i) => {
      o[header[i]] = el;
    })
    res.push(o);
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(parseCsv(csv));
```